# Get current ISO8601 date/time stamp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datetime, static

I would like to get the current date/time stamp of the server or client in ISO8601 format (ex. 31 Dec 2009, 02:53). I know that server time can be observed using PHP and brought into the DOM using jQuery $.getJson. Client side time can be recorded from the browser using javascript/jQuery. I want the time stamp to be static (not dynamic/real-time). Im php/JS newbie and would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Your example in ISO 8601 format would be 2009-12-31T02:53

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For JavaScript just create a new `Date` object like this

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

and then you can construct your date in any format you want using the methods that `Date` provides. See [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for the complete list of methods you can use.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
var months = Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');

var currentDate = new Date();
var formatedDate = currentDate.getDate() + ' ' + months[currentDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + currentDate.getFullYear() + ' ' + currentDate.getHours() + ':' + currentDate.getMinutes();
```

As for PHP it's as simple as this:

```
$formatedDate = date("c");
```

See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for full reference on the `Date()` function.

Comment: In PHP, Date("j M Y H:i") produces a date string formatted like "21 Aug 2012 23:48". This is certainly not ISO8601 format which was requested by the asker. ISO8601 format can be achieved with a simple date("c"). - @MagicMushroom

Answer (score 28):

In PHP 5, you can do

```
date("c"); //   ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)
```

see [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)